# Is it possible to name file currently represented as buffer without having write/read?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get data from the Postgres database as a "bytea" (this is how they are stored in the database), then using bytea-parser I turn it into a Node type "buffer" and I need to give this to the front-end as a file with the name, but currently it comes as an untitled file. Of course, I understand that I can write this file to disk and thus give it a name, but I would like to do without this operation (besides, I still have to read it - that a lot I/O). Is it possible? In other words, is it possible to have a file as a buffer and give it a name without having write/read I/O?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  You can set the `content-disposition` header.  See this [writeup on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) for more explanation, but if you want the user to be prompted to save the file to their hard drive, you would probably use something like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"
```

If you have any examples of responses (even if they use the disk for actual files) that work the way you want them in the browser, then you can look at exactly how that response is structured (use the Network tab in the Chrome debugger to see the actual http headers and content) and then you can emulate the appropriate headers and other parts of the response with your response.

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what i need. Marked as solution.